# Monthly reports (GA > Google Sheets > Excel) - automate the archiving process?

Tags: google-sheets, google-analytics, analytics

What I'm looking for, say I have a

```
Google Sheet: Col A - row titles such as conversions, page views etc.
Col B - January & stats 
Col C - February & stats
```

You get the idea.. now, for 2019 I could now pull data until March. What I'd like is that at the end of April, I could use the GA addon schedule function and EOMONTH to automatically pull in all of April's data.. and then create a column next to March filling in the data? So basically, every month it would move one column to the right.

I'm decent at using Python / SQL so would be open for suggestions but I'm quite limited in what I can use (IS department doesn't like me installing things other than Excel...). Is this possible and what I could use and then I can Google to find out more?

At the moment what I do for weekly reports is have the data automatically refresh Monday morning, then I copy/paste the data into the appropriate column.

Answer (score 0):

paste in **B1** cell and drag to the right:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("A"&EOMONTH(DATE(2019, COLUMN(A1), 1), -1)+1):
 INDIRECT("A"&EOMONTH(DATE(2019, COLUMN(A1), 1), 0)))))
```

[image: 0]